# Calling a ruby script from c#, process not exit

Tags: c#, ruby, process

I try to execute a .rb file from c#. Process never exits.

```
       var result = new Process
       {
           StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
           {
               FileName = "ruby \"someRubyFile.rb\"",
               UseShellExecute = false,
               CreateNoWindow = true
           }
       };
       result.Start();
       result.WaitForExit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured it out. If I send .rb filename as an argument, everthing works fine.